# How to make td background color green without using any state?

Tags: reactjs

I created one react project, In that project I have one component named it as Table. In Table.js, To td I am trying to pass color like Green, Red, Blue. But the problem is I have to do it without using any state so please help me to solve this.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table/Table';

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table></Table>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #09d3ac;
}
```

This is Table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Table.css'

export default class Table extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='tab'>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">S No</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Color</th>
                                    <th scope="col">colorName</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                    <td class="green">Green</td>
                                    <td>#0000ff</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                                    <td>Red</td>
                                    <td>#a52a2a</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                                    <td>Blue</td>
                                    <td>#6495ed</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is Table.css

```
Nothing is there in Table.css
```

In Table.js I have  In  I have  to that td I have to pass colors like Green, Red, Blue But I have to do this without using state.
If I am not clear with my doubt please comment your question.

Comment: You mean you need to update colours or you need to pass data inside? If it's data - possible, but not optimal solution - is to use a global variable.

Comment: In Table.js you can see like <td>Green</td>, <td>Red</td>, <td>Blue</td>. In output it is showing like Green, Red, Blue. I have to pass those td with Green, Red, Blue Colors. I have to do this without using state.

Comment: You mean that those `td` elements should have the same color as the name? If that's the case, you can set that color with CSS (in `Table.css`): `.green: color: green;`.